# How can I accomplish this AngularJS task?

Tags: angularjs

I placed the code I am working with here in [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/RfCrAu8PL9uT9TEzqyhC?p=preview) Plunker.

```
var arFloorStatus=['disabled','',''];
var spFloorStatus=['','','disabled'];
```

Those two arrays are parallel to:

```
var buildingFloors=['GR','01','02'];
```

Which shows which floors will be used.

This array contains all the possible floors:

```
var floors =[{
    name:"Ground Floor",
    initial:"GR",
},{
    name:"1st Floor",
    initial:"01",
},{
    name:"2nd Floor",
    initial:"02",
},{
    name:"3rd Floor",
    initial:"03",
}];
```

The for loop searches through `buildingFloors` and `floors` to create two objects:

```
for(i=0;i<buildingFloors.length;i++){
  for(c=0;c<floors.length;c++){
    if(floors[c].initial == buildingFloors[i]){
        $scope.arFiles.push({
          floor:floors[i].name, initial:floors[i].initial, status:arFloorStatus[c]
        });
        $scope.spFiles.push({
          floor:floors[i].name, initial:floors[i].initial, status:spFloorStatus[c]
        });
    }
  }
}
```

In `arFiles` the Ground Floor (GR) is "disabled" and in spFiles the 2nd Floor (02) is "disabled". **I want to put a button in that changes which object is being used.** Right now, `spFiles` is shown using an `ng-repeat`:

```
<tr ng-repeat = "x in spFiles">
    <th scope="row">{{x.floor}}</th>
    <td>AR{{x.initial}}.pdf {{x.status}} {{x.labelname}}</td>
    <td>AR{{x.initial}}.dwf {{x.status}} {{x.labelname2}}</td>
    <td>AR{{x.initial}}.dwg {{x.status}} {{x.labelname3}}</td>
</tr>
```

My first thought was to clone the object and instead of the ng-repeat containing `spFiles` it could contain a generic name that is a clone of whichever object is set to be used, but cloning objects seemed too overly complicated for my task. I was hoping there was a more "Angular way" to accomplish my task, but I am unsure how to go about it.

Along the lines of:

```
$scope.switchObj = function(newObj){
    if(newObj == "ar"){
        //somehow switch the object being used in the ng-repeat.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "cloning" ?

This should work:

```
<tr ng-repeat = "x in files">
    <th scope="row">{{x.floor}}</th>
    <td>AR{{x.initial}}.pdf {{x.status}} {{x.labelname}}</td>
    <td>AR{{x.initial}}.dwf {{x.status}} {{x.labelname2}}</td>
    <td>AR{{x.initial}}.dwg {{x.status}} {{x.labelname3}}</td>
</tr>
```

And affect the files that you want to display in the `files` variable

```
$scope.switchObj = function(newObj){
    if(newObj == "ar"){
        $scope.files = newObj;
    }
}
```

See the following working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/E3MPAt39LCCswg9N4V9T?p=preview